# IS there a UITableView with alphabetic or numeric index in the view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a specific UITableView set of methods that will generate a UItableView with an alphabetic or numeric index along the side similar to what appears when you bring up the AddressBook?

I want to provide a large amount of data from a datasource in a table listing format with an accessible index on the display similar to AddressBook.  The AddressBook has the alphabet displayed on the right, which the user can tap to be taken down to that level of detail.  I need to do something similar.

I want to use a numeric index.  It would be "nice to have" either an alphabetical or numeric accessible indexed UITableView.

I did search Apple's documentation as well as StackOverFlow, didn't find anything, but who knows, I may be blind and not even know it. :)

Do I have to subclass UITableView?  Or is there freeware framework available somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

this is asked and answered a few times, basically it behavior that is built in, you will need to support more delegate/datasource methods.

the main method is [`– sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView%3a) 
and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` keep in mind that this only works in plain style tableViews.

Comment: Yep, I must be blind.  I'll look at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method

```
sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
```

Asks the data source to return the titles for the sections for a table view.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Parameters

tableView - The table-view object requesting this information.

Return Value

An array of strings that serve as the title of sections in the table view and appear in the index list on the right side of the table view. The table view must be in the plain style (UITableViewStylePlain). For example, for an alphabetized list, you could return an array containing strings “A” through “Z”.

Comment: :P, dont worry, happens to all of us